# Immersed Surfaces in Hyperbolic Space with Positive Intrinsic Curvature

Tags: differential-geometry

Does anyone know of an example of a noncompact, immersed surface in hyperbolic 3-space with positive intrinsic curvature that is NOT embedded?

Comment: There are no noncompact, complete, surfaces with positive intrinsic curvature. This is due to Myers' theorem. Thus any example would have to be incomplete.

Comment: An immersion of a surface is a map from a surface into an ambient space. The image of the immersion may well have self-intersections. But Myers' theorem applies to the domain, provided that it is complete.

Comment: You might want to look at the so called `extrinsic' curvature instead, i.e. the difference between the intrinsic and the ambient curvatures. Check out Hadamard's theorem, which says that any immersion of positively curved surface into $\mathbb R^3$ is embedded. Probably you can use the same proof to say that any immersion of a surface into hyperbolic $3$-space with positive extrinsic curvature is an embedding. This would seem to answer your question.

Comment: @treble: Myers's theorem applies only when the curvature is bounded below by a positive constant.  It's possible to have complete metrics on noncompact manifolds with positive curvature everywhere, as long as the curvature gets arbitrarily close to zero.

Comment: @JackLee Yes, of course you are right. My mistake. Still, I feel like one should be able to use the sign on the second fundamental form to rule out the possibility of self-intersections.

Comment: Who made the conjecture?